# Login script for bash not loading

Tags: bash, shell, login, bashrc, dash

I am very confused about the login script for bash. I have always used `~/.bash_profile` to configure my bash shell. Now I am on a new system just as a user: I am not root. This system was originally using tcsh shell and I changed it to bash using the command `ypchsh to /bin/sh`, but it does not load my bash login configuration file and not even `.bashrc`. But if I type just

`bash`

in my terminal, my login file is loaded. What should I do to load it on login?

---

sample of my .profile:

```
# .bash_profile

 # Get the aliases and functions
 if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
         . ~/.bashrc
 fi

 # User specific environment and startup programs

 PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/share/bin/:/usr/local/share/bin/idl/:./
 export PATH

 source $HOME/script.sh

 export SCRIPT_VARIABLE
```

Comment: Have you checked if shell changed? Try `getent passwd \`whoami\`` or just `ps` right after login.

Comment: I have printed echo $SHELL and the result is /bin/sh

Comment: This may or may not help: [Which setup files should be used for setting up environment variables with bash?](http://superuser.com/questions/183845/which-setup-files-should-be-used-for-setting-up-environment-variables-with-bash) What distribution are you running? How do you log in (text mode, GUI, remotely? If GUI, what program do you type your password into?)? If you run a desktop environment after loggin in, which one?

Comment: I am running scientific linux release 5.8. I log in with a GUI and I use gnome

Answer (score 2):

On some systems, `/bin/sh` is not `bash` (e.g. on Ubuntu, it is `/bin/dash`). Set your `.profile` for `/bin/sh`, use `.bash_profile` only for `/bin/bash`.

Comment: I have tried, it doesn't work

Comment: @simona: What distribution do you use? How do you log in?

Comment: it is called scientific linux release 5.8 (Boron), I log in graphically

Comment: @simona What did you try, what doesn't work?

Comment: in effect it works, because it defines the variables I define in .profile and execute a script. but it looks like it does not load the configurations for the shell I put in .bashrc and the aliases that are defined there. I put my .profile in the main question, for reference

Comment: @simona: As I already indicated, `/bin/dash` is not `/bin/bash`, therefore it does not read `.bashrc`. Please clarify what you mean by "it looks like it does not load etc."

Comment: but it reads .profile, that is reported in the question, hence it should execute .bashrc because the file exists, shouldn't it? I mean that the alias that are defined in .bashrc are not loaded and the prompt is not personalized as specified in .bashrc

Comment: The shell may not recognize the `~` character as a substitute for $HOME? Try changing it to `$HOME/.bashrc`.